# Hide one specific row in sharepoint using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint

I have the following problem in sharepoint 2010.  For some reason the _cts folder is shown in all document libraries, I have researched for days and I have found no reason for this, so my best solution for now its to hide the entire row.

Please see screenshot here.

However I am not sure how to hide it via jquery

http://postimage.org/image/6qego8xg3/

```
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
      ctx = new ContextInfo();

      var existingHash = '';
      if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1){
        existingHash = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("#"));
      }
      ctx.existingServerFilterHash = existingHash;
      if (ctx.existingServerFilterHash.indexOf("ServerFilter=") == 1) {
        ctx.existingServerFilterHash = ctx.existingServerFilterHash.replace(/-/g, '&').replace(/&&/g, '-');
        var serverFilterRootFolder = GetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder", true,ctx.existingServerFilterHash);
        var currentRootFolder = GetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder", true);
        if("" == serverFilterRootFolder && "" != currentRootFolder)
        {
          ctx.existingServerFilterHash += "&RootFolder=" + currentRootFolder;
        }
        window.location.hash = '';
        window.location.search = '?' + ctx.existingServerFilterHash.substr("ServerFilter=".length + 1);
      }

          ctx.listBaseType = 1;

      ctx.NavigateForFormsPages = false;
      ctx.listTemplate = "30009";
      ctx.listName = "{55607631-9F43-4F52-B759-E9003D258CC0}";
      ctx.view = "{46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}";
      ctx.listUrlDir = "/apps/x/DocsOut";
      ctx.HttpPath = "http://sharepointluis/apps/x/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001";
      ctx.HttpRoot = "http://sharepointluis/apps/x";
      ctx.imagesPath = "/_layouts/images/";
      ctx.PortalUrl = "";
      ctx.SendToLocationName = "";
      ctx.SendToLocationUrl = "";

          ctx.RecycleBinEnabled = 1;

      ctx.OfficialFileName = "";
      ctx.OfficialFileNames = "";
      ctx.WriteSecurity = "1";
      ctx.SiteTitle = "x";
      ctx.ListTitle = "Outgoing Document";
      if (ctx.PortalUrl == "") ctx.PortalUrl = null;
      ctx.displayFormUrl = "http://sharepointluis/apps/x/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={55607631-9F43-4F52-B759-E9003D258CC0}";
      ctx.editFormUrl = "http://sharepointluis/apps/x/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId={55607631-9F43-4F52-B759-E9003D258CC0}";
      ctx.isWebEditorPreview = 0;
      ctx.ctxId = 9;
      ctx.isXslView = true;

      if (g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap["{46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}"] == null)
          g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap["{46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}"]= 9;
      ctx.CurrentUserId = 1073741823;

        ctx.verEnabled = 1;

        ctx.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

      ctx9 = ctx;
      g_ctxDict['ctx9'] = ctx;
    </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/vbscript>
    On Error Resume Next
    Set EditDocumentButton = CreateObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3")
    If (IsObject(EditDocumentButton)) Then
        fNewDoc3 = true
    Else
        Set EditDocumentButton = CreateObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.2")
        If (IsObject(EditDocumentButton)) Then
            fNewDoc2 = true
        Else
            Set EditDocumentButton = CreateObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1")
        End If
    End If    
    fNewDoc = IsObject(EditDocumentButton)
      </SCRIPT>

<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><IFRAME style="DISPLAY: none" id=FilterIframe9 height=0 src="javascript:false;" width=0 name=FilterIframe9 FilterLink="?"></IFRAME>
<TABLE id=onetidDoclibViewTbl0 class=ms-listviewtable border=0 cellSpacing=0 summary="Outgoing Document " cellPadding=1 width="100%" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" o:WebQuerySourceHref="http://sharepointluis/apps/x/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&amp;XMLDATA=1&amp;RowLimit=0&amp;View={46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}" handleDeleteInit="true">
<TBODY>
<TR class="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr" vAlign=top>
<TH class=ms-vh-icon scope=col><INPUT class=s4-selectAllCbx title="Select or deselect all items" onclick=ToggleAllItems(event,this,9) value="" type=checkbox></TH>
<TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="Edit" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=Edit&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Computed" DisplayName="Edit" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="FALSE" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable="FALSE">Edit</DIV></TH>
<TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="DocIcon" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=DocIcon&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Computed" DisplayName="Type" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortDocIcon onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=DocIcon&amp;SortDir=Asc">Type<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
<DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH oncontextmenu="" class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) onmouseout="" onclick="" scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="LinkFilename" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=LinkFilename&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Computed" DisplayName="Name" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="FALSE" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortLinkFilename onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=LinkFilename&amp;SortDir=Asc">Name<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
<DIV style="LINE-HEIGHT: 32px; MARGIN: 0px; HEIGHT: 32px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 278px" class=s4-ctx shown="false"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"><IMG style="VISIBILITY: hidden" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/images/ecbarw.png" width=7 height=4></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="SentDate" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=SentDate&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="DateTime" DisplayName="SentDate" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortSentDate onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=SentDate&amp;SortDir=Asc">SentDate<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
<DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH oncontextmenu="" class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) onmouseout="" onclick="" scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="ContentType" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=ContentType&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Computed" DisplayName="Content Type" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable="FALSE">Content Type</DIV>
<DIV style="LINE-HEIGHT: 32px; MARGIN: 0px; HEIGHT: 32px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 591px" class=s4-ctx shown="false"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"><IMG style="VISIBILITY: hidden" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/images/ecbarw.png" width=7 height=4></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="OutgoingDocumentType" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=OutgoingDocumentType&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="OutgoingDocumentType" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortOutgoingDocumentType onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=OutgoingDocumentType&amp;SortDir=Asc">OutgoingDocumentType<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
<DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="OutgoingMailType" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=OutgoingMailType&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="OutgoingMailType" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortOutgoingMailType onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=OutgoingMailType&amp;SortDir=Asc">OutgoingMailType<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
<DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
<DIV class=ms-vh-div name="OutgoingDocumentStatus" SortFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=OutgoingDocumentStatus&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="OutgoingDocumentStatus" CTXNum="9" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortOutgoingDocumentStatus onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={46c9a371-28ff-4003-aa75-46098aa5104b}&amp;SortField=OutgoingDocumentStatus&amp;SortDir=Asc">OutgoingDocumentStatus<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
<DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH></TR>
<TR class=ms-itmhover iid="9,1,1" setEdgeBorder="true">
<TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="_cts&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb-icon><A onclick="EditItemWithCheckoutAlert(event, 'http://sharepointluis/apps/x/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId={55607631-9F43-4F52-B759-E9003D258CC0}&amp;ID=1', '0', '0', '%2Fapps%x%2FDocsOut%2F%5Fcts', 'http://sharepointluis/apps/x', '', '1073741823');return false;" href="http://sharepointluis/apps/x/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId={55607631-9F43-4F52-B759-E9003D258CC0}&amp;ID=1" target=_self><IMG border=0 alt=Edit src="/_layouts/images/edititem.gif"></A></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb-icon><A onmousedown="VerifyFolderHref(this, event, '','FALSE','1', '', '', '')" onclick="return HandleFolder(this,event,&quot;/apps/x/DocsOut/Forms/LastModified.aspx?RootFolder=&quot; + escapeProperly(&quot;/apps/x/DocsOut/_cts&quot;) + '&amp;FolderCTID=0x010100709EF428D547F5428D5B747B7761A269&amp;View={46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}','TRUE','FALSE','','FALSE','1','','','','','1073741823','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff');" href="/apps/x/DocsOut/Forms/LastModified.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fapps%x%2FDocsOut%2F%5Fcts&amp;FolderCTID=0x010100709EF428D547F5428D5B747B7761A269&amp;View={46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}"><IMG title="Folder: _cts" border=0 alt="Folder: _cts" src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif"></A></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb-title onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
<DIV id=1 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkFilename" CTXName="ctx9"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onmousedown="&#13;&#10;                  javascript:VerifyFolderHref(this,event,'','FALSE','1','','','');return false;&#13;&#10;                " onclick="&#13;&#10;                  return HandleFolder(this,event,&quot;/apps/x/DocsOut/Forms/LastModified.aspx?RootFolder=&quot; + escapeProperly(&quot;/apps/x/DocsOut/_cts&quot;) + '&amp;FolderCTID=0x010100709EF428D547F5428D5B747B7761A269&amp;View={46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}','TRUE','FALSE','','FALSE','1','','','','','1073741823','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff');&#13;&#10;                " href="/apps/x/DocsOut/Forms/LastModified.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fapps%x%2FDocsOut%2F%5Fcts&amp;FolderCTID=0x010100709EF428D547F5428D5B747B7761A269&amp;View={46C9A371-28FF-4003-AA75-46098AA5104B}">_cts</A></DIV>
<DIV style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; MARGIN: 0px; HEIGHT: 22px; TOP: 34px; LEFT: 278px" class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;" shown="false"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"><IMG style="VISIBILITY: hidden" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/images/ecbarw.png" width=7 height=4></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2><NOBR></NOBR></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2>Document</TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
<TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
<TD class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell"></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>HideListViewRows("onetidDoclibViewTbl0");</SCRIPT>
</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Comment: When do you want to hide your row? Means after selecting one row are you clicking any button in the ribbon or you want to hide at the moment you selected the row?

Comment: @Mihir when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('#msomenuid2').closest('tr').remove();
```

**Edit:**

```
$('td:contains("_cts")').closest('tr').remove();
```

**Edit 2:**

```
$('td > div[ctsname]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == '_cts';
}).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: it has to be something generic that works in all sharepoint pages, something that I can add into the masterpage and it works everywhere and always removes the _cts row

Comment: its hiding all the entire webpart, not just the row.

Comment: Are you sure? The code seem right. Can you recreate the situation using http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I just edited the post and posted the entire table generated by sharepoint, my guess is that its because there are nested tables.

Comment: Added another possible solution

Comment: please explain why ctsname, am I supposed to replace ctsname with something??? the code itself does not hide anything

Comment: this is the code I am tryin g<script src="/_layouts/Scripts/jquery1.8.1.min.js"></script><script language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
$('td > div[ctsname]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == '_cts';
}).closest('tr').remove();
});</script>